# What is the next string lexicographically?

Tags: string

I'm a bit confused about the lexicographical order of strings.

So if my `s = "zzz"`, what is the next, i.e. "zzz"+1, if I can say so? Is it `"zzza"` or `"azzz"`?

Add: my alphabet for this question is [a..z].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when considering lexicographical order you must define the length of a longest word. Unless you do that, getting the next word in order means appending first letter of an alphabet to the previous word. It means that starting from `"a"` you can't even get to the word `"b"` in finite number of steps (since words such as `"aa", "aaa"...` are all before `"b"` in that ordering).

If you want to generate consecutive words over an alphabet you should use cannonical order in which:

1. Shorter words are before longer words
2. If two words have the same length they are sorted alphabetically

In this scenario next word after `"zzz"` would be "`aaaa`" which seems a bit counter-intuitive but allows you get the `n-th` word over the alphabet in a more useful fashion.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on your character set to know which is the next one but `"azzz"` is way before `"zzz"` while `"zzza"` is after `"zzz"`.

It's the same order as a dictionary:
`a..z` then `aa..az` then `ba..bz` etc